# Handle file saving/loading on another thread

Tags: java

I've been working on a file/loading method for my project. I'm currently using a pool of worker-threads with a queue of all the IO tasks. There is a timer that runs every 50MS that checks whether or not the queue is empty and executes all the tasks within the queue. All the tasks are added to the queue from various threads that CANNOT be delayed from IO or waiting for the worker threads to complete a task.

Is there alternative solution for what i'm trying to achieve? Like adding a wait that only applies to the worker threads rather then the threads attempting to put IO tasks within them.

Edit: I'd also like to avoid constantly creating new Thread objects. It seems to have a pretty big impact on my applications performance.

Comment: Well, using a timer to poll a queue seems like a bad idea.  I think an ExecutorService might be a better idea here.

Comment: markspace, would execute(Runnable command) force the calling thread to wait until the Executer's threads to be ready to be used?

Comment: Yes, if there were no threads available, and your thread pool has a maximum number of allowable threads (a good idea).  However, a timer always forces tasks to wait, so the two aren't any different in that regard.

Comment: @markspace Well see there's the issue. I can't have my main thread pausing to wait for an executors thread(s) to be available. That's why i introduced my Queue .